# Android - Facebook Share Button not working

Tags: android, facebook, android-button, facebook-share

I'm trying to integrate `Facebook` with my android music app. My requirement is to share listening music on `Facebook`

Added `ShareButton` on my activity layout , but the `ShareButton` is not `clickable`

```
 <com.facebook.share.widget.ShareButton
                android:id="@+id/fb_share_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:enabled="true"/>
```

OnClick Listener

```
@Click(R.id.fb_share_button)
protected void onFacebookShareClicked(){
     ShareLinkContent shareLinkContent = getLinkContent();
    mFacebookShareButton.setShareContent(shareLinkContent);
    mShareDialog.show(shareLinkContent);
}
```

I don't find any document on this . No idea how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have missed a few steps. Rather than copying the steps here, I will link you to the page. Specifically look at the steps for **Share Button** and **Share Dialog**. Provided you have set up the facebook SDK properly, this should work.
[Facebook SDK Android Docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android)